# Most concise way to do "not contained in"?

Tags: java, haskell

Coming from Haskell I was used to have concise operators like

```
not ("x" `elem` ["a","b","c"])
```

What is the most concise way to do that in plain old java, e.g. for an if-clause?

Lists? Arrays? Helper-Function? That feels so ugly and overly verbose ...

Comment: Even more concise: `notElem "x" ["a","b","c"]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `contains` method in java collections:

for example:

```
ArrayList<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrList.add("One");
arrList.add("Two");
arrList.add("Three");

if( ! arrList.contains("Four"))
{
    System.out.println("item not contained");
}
```

Comment: I accept this one for further discussion. Someone notes the 4 long lines compared to the Haskell approach ?

Comment: @Bastl well, you could shorten it up a bit: `! Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three").contains("Four")`. If you're worried about extra clutter going from Haskell to Java, this is going to be the least of your problems... :)

Comment: ah yes, that looks ok to me :-) nearly looks like composing functions.

Comment: @Bastl: you can sort of think of `.` as flowing the other way in function composition. `baz . bar $ foo` translates to `foo.bar().baz()`

Answer (score 4):

[Collection#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
 if(!collection.contains(object))
```

Comment: but you have to create the collection object first :-/

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [lambdaj](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) project. It will give you back some of the functional tools you miss.

Answer (score 1):

With [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries):

```
!ImmutableList.of("a", "b", "c").contains("x")
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Frege](http://code.google.com/p/frege):

```
not ("x" `elem` ["a","b","c"])
```

The Java code will be generated by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with any collection: `!collection.contains(x)`. A `Set`, and in particular `HashSet`, is probably going to be the fastest for this kind of operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a character lookup, you can use

```
if ("abc".indexOf(ch) < 0)
```